# Asp.Net Core & Angular - Clear Cache After Uploading New Version

Tags: c#, angular, caching, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core application (version 2.2) that serves a angular 7 application. I want to force the client to clear the cache after we upload a new version to production. I know that the recommended way to do this, is by manipulating the file query string, but since I use ISpaBuilder I'm not sure how to do this.

```js
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60); // Increase the timeout if angular app is taking longer to startup
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200"); // Use this instead to use the angular cli server
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try to check [React template index.html caching? #3147](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3147#issuecomment-435617378)